# how to avoid a nested for loop in this problem

Tags: java, loops, optimization, java-8, nested

given these object

**Test**

```
 int one;
 int two;
 List<AnotherObject> testList.
```

**AnotherObject**

```
 string name;
 int three; 
 List<AthirdObject> anotherList;
```

**AThirdObject**

```
 string surname;
 int    id;
```

assuming we have List < Test > how can i reach AThirdObject without using a nested for loop , thx in advance

Comment: Something in the code will be doing a nested loop, whether you actually see it or not.

Comment: i kinda knew it but its more like a syntactic sugar

Comment: Do you want to get all the elements or just one ?

Comment: i want all elements

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Stream::flatMap` should be used here to provide "access" to the lowest level of nested lists assuming the getters are implemented properly in the sample classes:

```java
List<Test> input = ...; // define input data

List<AThirdObject> nestedList = input
    .stream() // Stream<Test>
    .flatMap(t -> t.getTestList().stream()) // Stream<AnotherObject>
    .flatMap(ao -> ao.getAnotherList().stream()) // Stream<AThirdObject>
    .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Comment: I appreciate the answer and thanks for your time I implemented it and it works